# PHP function run on click

Tags: javascript, php, function, onclick

I'm trying to run a php function on click as shown below but it just returns a 500 error. I've tried this

```
function doakrim(){
    echo "Test";
}
while (list($key, $val) = each($handlinger))
{
   echo '<tr onclick="document.write('<?php doakrim(); ?>');"><td>'. $val .'</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>';
}
```

but that just return a 500 error on my webpage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this PHP-CLI? I mean, PHP code on a webserver is executed BEFORE sending the page to the client, so it is impossible to catch the client's click; that must be caught with client-side scripting (i.e. javascript).

Comment: `<?php` in PHP is an error. Also JS can't execute PHP. For the exact error message turn on error reporting or check your logs..

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a PHP function from within the javascript, however its possible to inject the value you need within your javascript's **.write** method.

I cant see a happy ending for the provided example above:) maybe it's best to first clarify what is exactly the problem?

But if you have to make it functional here is a slightly cleaner approach

```
function doakrim()
{
    return "Test";
}

while (list($key, $val) = each($handlinger)) {
    echo '<tr onclick="document.write(\''. doakrim() .'\');"><td>'. $val .'</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>';
}
```

there is chance what you really need is an [Ajax](http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2013/03/12/what-is-ajax-and-where-is-it-used-in-technology) call to fetch the **doakrim** result back from a server, but its hard to say before knowing what exactly you want to achieve :)